# Clicking on notification does not open app in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, notification, gnome-shell

In my Ubuntu 18.04, clicking on a notification in the message tray no longer opens or switches to the relevant application (such as Geary). The notification is simply dismissed when I click it.

Where do I need to check and fix what went wrong here? I've tried looking at dconf settings and reset them, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the problem?

Comment: It is still an issue in ubuntu 23.04 (anger emoji here)