# App not opening when clicked on notification in the notification panel

Tags: gnome, notification, 23.10

While clicking on a notification pop-up, I can switch to the respective application. But while clicking the message in the notification panel, it no longer opens or switches to the relevant application. The notification gets dismissed when I click it.

I checked online for this issue and could only find this similar unanswered question in **AskUbuntu**: [Clicking on notification does not open the app in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048458/clicking-on-notification-does-not-open-app-in-18-04). I am asking this question again since 18.04 has reached it's **[End-of-Life](https://ubuntu.com/blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support)**.

**My system details:**

```
OS: Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64
Host: Inspiron 15 3511
Kernel: 6.5.0-14-generic
CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-1135G7
DE: GNOME 45.1
```

EDIT: **How to reproduce this issue**

- Get a notification from your installed application (in my case slack).
- Open the notification from the notification panel (not the pop-up that comes when we receive it). You can now see that the message disappears instead of opening the application.

[image: notification-open]

Comment: This could indeed be a bug. If you could provide an example on how to trigger a notification, readers could more easily test whether they can reproduce or not.

Comment: @vanadium, I have updated the question. Kindly check now

Comment: Could you create a new user and see if the problem persists there too?

Comment: @JohnCarter I did. I even installed Ubuntu in another system and faced the same issue. Are you guys getting redirected to the application when clicking on the notification??

Comment: I have just installed slack and the same problem occurs. I guess this is a bug with the app itself.

Comment: @JohnCarter I tested the same with my browsers (Brave, Chrome, Firefox) and none opened the window when I clicked on the notification.

Comment: I can easily reproduce the issue on Fedora. I searched for [notification issues in gnome-shell GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/?sort=created_date&state=opened&search=notification&first_page_size=20), but couldn't find a report about it. However, I'm pretty sure that the issue is a bug that should be reported to [gnome-shell GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell) or against the [gnome-shell package in Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell). Unfortunately, I don't think we can do something to workaround the issue till GNOME fixes it.

Comment: For me, the bug does not occur in 24.04. But you can try to reproduce the error with either zenity (zenity --notitification --text="Text") or Python (notifications library). There you should get at least an error/warning message. Without a bit more data, it seems hopeless.